# How to accept http requests after shutdown signal in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I tried this:

```
void onShutdown(@Observes final ShutdownEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
    log.infof("ShutdownEvent received, waiting for %s seconds before shutting down", shutdownWaitSeconds);
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(shutdownWaitSeconds);
    log.info("Continue shutting down");
}
```

But after receiving `ShutdownEvent` Quarkus already responds with 503 to http requests. Looks like this could be done with [ShutdownListener](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/core/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/runtime/shutdown/ShutdownListener.java) in `preShutdown` method. I have implemented this listener but it does not get called yet. How do I register `ShutdownListener`?

Use case here is OpenShift sending requests to terminating pod.

Comment: It seems to me you're trying to manually implement what's already there: https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#graceful-shutdown

Comment: That graceful shutdown is different thing. During this graceful shutdown period Quarkus does not accept any new http requests.

Comment: To clarify, we need that graceful shutdown period too but it won't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1: Create Quarkus extension**

Instructions are [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-my-first-extension). `ShutdownController` is my own class implementing `ShutdownListener` where I have a sleep in `preShutdown` method.

```
class ShutdownControllerProcessor {

    @BuildStep
    FeatureBuildItem feature() {
        return new FeatureBuildItem("shutdown-controller");
    }

    @BuildStep
    ShutdownListenerBuildItem shutdownListener() {
        // Called at build time. Default constructor will be called at runtime.
        // Getting MethodNotFoundException when calling default constructor here.
        return new ShutdownListenerBuildItem(new ShutdownController(10));
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Modify ShutdownRecorder private static final field**

New shutdown listener can be added using reflection. This is a bit ugly solution.

`registerIfNeeded()` need to be called after Quarkus startup, for example with timer 1 second after `@PostConstruct`.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ListenerRegisterer {

    public void registerIfNeeded() {
        try {
            tryToRegister();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    private void tryToRegister() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        final var field = ShutdownRecorder.class.getDeclaredField("shutdownListeners");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        final var listeners = (List<ShutdownListener>) field.get(null);
        if (listeners != null && !listeners.toString().contains("ShutdownController")) {
            listeners.add(new ShutdownController(10));
            setFinalStatic(field, listeners);
        }
    }

    private static void setFinalStatic(final Field field, final Object newValue) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        final var modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(null, newValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share your solution? I am facing the same problem when trying to send an email when the application stops.

Comment: It is shared in this answer, do you have questions about it?

Comment: yes. Using option 2, is this correct way to call registerIfNeeded function?  

```
@QuarkusMain
public class ApplicationRunner {
  @Inject ListenerRegisterer listenerRegisterer;

  @PostConstruct
  void setListenerRegisterer(){
    listenerRegisterer.registerIfNeeded();
  }
```

Comment: Maybe, I used Vert.x timer in `@PostConstruct` to delay setting the listener for 1-2 sec to avoid overwrite.