# Send an email when application shuts down

Tags: quarkus

I need to send an email when the application shuts down.
I have created the following method:

```
   void onStop(@Observes ShutdownEvent event) throws ParserConfigurationException {
    mailer.send(Mail.withText("test@email.com","STOP TEST", "HERE IS STOP A TEST"));
    Quarkus.waitForExit();
  }
```

But I always receive the following error:

```
│ Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)                                                                   │
│     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)                                                                          │
│     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)                                                   │
│     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)                                            │
│     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)                                                     │
│     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)                                                                     │
│     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)                                                                                       │
│     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)                                   │
│     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)                      │
│     ... 32 more
```

I am quite sure that all the connections are closed when I am trying to send the email. This is very similar to the question asked here -> [How to accept http requests after shutdown signal in Quarkus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70957248/how-to-accept-http-requests-after-shutdown-signal-in-quarkus/70968884#70968884), but not clear to me how to implement the solution he proposes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This really looks like an issue connection to your mail server (SMTP perhaps?)  Can you connect to it when the container is not in the process of stopping?

Comment: Yes, without any problem.

Comment: How does the linked issue which tries to accept incoming requests after shutdown signal relate to your issue?  What is `mailer`? Can you confirm that this object and the configuration objects that it depends on are the same during normal operation time and shutdown time to see thst you are indeed sending a request to your mail server during shutdown?